# Powercenter - concurrent target instances

Tags: concurrency, target, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have a situation where we have a different execution order of instances of the same target being loaded from a single source qualifier. 
We have a problem when we promote a mapping from DEV to TEST when we execute in TEST after promoting there are problems.

For instance we have a router with 3 groups for Insert, Update and Delete followed by the appropriate update strategies to set the row type accordingly followed by three target instances.

```
RTR ----> UPD_Insert -----> TGT_Insert
      \
       \__>   UPD_Update -------> TGT_Update
        \
         \__>  UPD_Delete --------->  TGT_Delete
```

When we test this out using data to do an insert followed by an update followed by a delete all based on the same primary key we get a different execution order in TEST compared to the same data in our DEV environment.

Anyone have any thoughts - I would post an image but I don't have enough cred yet.

Cheers,

Gil.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz the data comes from CDC so the order reflects the actual sequence of events to be replicated on the target, thus it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not controll the load order as long as you have a single source. I you could separate the loads to use separate sources the target load order setting in the mapping could be used, or you could even create separate mappings for them.
As it is now you should use a single target and utilize the update strategy transformation to determine the wanted operation for each record passing through. It is then possible to use a sort to define in what order the different operations is made to the physical table.

Comment: Maybe a sort could be enough even without changing the mapping.

Comment: Missing the point, in that we are trying to keep the sequence of events the same as the updates that are happening at source via a CDC read. The CDC read gets the data rows is in the correct sequence the problem is the block natue of the DTM engine is upsetting that sequence once it writes to 3 instances of the same target from that single source.

Comment: We can not split into all inserts followed by all updates followed by all deletes as this is not reflective of the source sequence of events and would damage the data integrity.

Comment: Rows are in constant insert, update and delete on the same primary key throughout the business day the CDC applies all of that in one overnight run hence the sequence is vital. 
Have now changed the logic to use a single target with setting the insert, update, delete in an Update Strategy and using a dynamic lookup cache, far to complicated for what is logically a simple set of operations as in my original design & posting ... just my twopence worth
Cheers,
Gil.

Comment: Ok, I missed that. But if your records come in the correct order already you just skip the sort. If you use 1 target and use the update strategy to code each record properly should be ok. Remember to set you session to treat source rows as "data driven" or the update strategy won't work.

Comment: @Gil why do you need a dynamic lookup? The posed problem should not need that, or am I missing something?

Comment: So, in one overnight run you could insert, update and delete the same primary key. Maintaining the data across that within the same mapping means using a dynamic lookup cache.
We have both created and updated timestamps on the target and we need to maintain these consistently too.

Comment: Yes, as long as you make sure that all records are correct (I get why you need the dynamic lookup now) and in a correct order it should work fine. Informatica will execute each an every record in that order and make it an insert, delete or update based on how you code it in update strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sorter transformation just before update strategy......based on update strategy condition you can sort the incoming rows....So first date will go through the Insert, than update at last through delete strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is try renaming the target definition in alphabetical order... like `INSERT_A`, `UPDATE_B`, `DELETE_C` then start loading

This will load in A,B,C order. Try and let me know